# MySQL chops off characters from md5 password

Tags: mysql, md5

I'm developing a website locally using XAMPP. There is a registration page in which I save the password, after encrypting it with **MD5**, to a MySQL database. The problem is that when I try to log in, I'm unable to. I discovered that the password was the problem. I checked the database and compared the MD5-ed password with the one I logged in with (I just echoed the MD5 hash of the password onto the page to compare). I found that the one in the database was shorter than the one echoed. My conclusion was that MySQL was chopping off some characters at the end of the hash. What should I do? I know it has to do with some settings on MySQL but I need help.

As at now, I have to use *substr* function on the hash in the registration and login processes so as to be able to log in.

Comment: What type/size is the column in the database - can it fit the md5 hash?

Comment: Is the field the right size? Is your parameterized query maybe chopping something? Show us your code!

Comment: Post your table definition: `show create table`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the column length is causing the problem, alter the column to accept a longer length.  MD5's are always 32 hex digits, so VARCHAR(32) would be a good option.

Comment: I'd say this is the most likely answer.

Comment: Thanks so much. Silly me. I was actually using varchar(14). I created the database with the intention of storing actual password strings. I'm a PHP newbie. Thanks once again

Answer (score 2):

It depends by the length of the value in the database ... check your field in the database and verify that his type is atleast something like a **varchar(32)**

To fix it you can use a query like that

```
ALTER TABLE Example
 MODIFY password  varchar(32)
```

or use the phpMyAdmin interface